# How to merge two list to key value into an associative array

Tags: python

I have this two list:

**List 1:**

> ['Site', 'admNrRbDifferentiationThr', 'admNrRrcDifferentiationThr',
> 'admResourceMinQciPrio', 'arpBasedPreEmptionState',
> 'dlAdmDifferentiationThr', 'dlAdmOverloadThr', 'dlMbmsGbrRatio',
> 'dlTransNwBandwidth', 'lbAtoThresholdLevel1', 'lbAtoThresholdLevel2',
> 'nrOfPaConnReservationsPerCell', 'nrOfRbReservationsPerPaConn',
> 'paArpOverride', 'resourceReservationForDifferentiation',
> 'resourceReservationForPAState', 'ulAdmDifferentiationThr',
> 'ulAdmOverloadThr', 'ulTransNwBandwidth', 'zzzTemp1', 'zzzTemp10',
> 'zzzTemp11', 'zzzTemp12', 'zzzTemp13', 'zzzTemp14', 'zzzTemp15',
> 'zzzTemp16', 'zzzTemp17', 'zzzTemp18', 'zzzTemp19', 'zzzTemp2',
> 'zzzTemp3', 'zzzTemp4', 'zzzTemp5', 'zzzTemp6', 'zzzTemp7',
> 'zzzTemp8', 'zzzTemp9', 'zzzTemporary1', 'zzzTemporary2',
> 'zzzTemporary3', 'zzzTemporary4', 'zzzTemporary5', 'zzzTemporary6',
> 'zzzTemporary7', 'zzzTemporary22', 'zzzTemporary23', 'zzzTemporary24',
> 'zzzTemporary25', 'zzzTemporary26']

**List 2:**

> [['MZL517', 750, 750, 5, 1, 500, 950, 200, 1000, 30, 45, 1, 4, 7, 5,
> 0, 500, 950, 1000, -1, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000,
> 1000, 1000, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, nan, nan, nan,
> nan, -2000000000, -2000000000, -2000000000, -2000000000, -2000000000,
> -2000000000, -2000000000, -2000000000]]

**My expected result:**

> {'site': 'MZL517', 'admNrRbDifferentiationThr': '750',
> 'admNrRrcDifferentiationThr': '750Science'} ...

Comment: You need to write some code, even if it's inefficient, or doesn't quite work, so we can help you. Otherwise you're asking us to do your homework.

Comment: `result = dict(zip(list_1, list_2))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be achieved using python's zip function like the following:

Since your `list_2` is list of list, hence I have done `list_2[0]`.

```py
print(dict(zip(list_1, list_2[0])))
```